# Load huge image from file

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, openglrenderer

I'm using pictures which are stored on the **Environment.getDataDirectory()** and they are 1920 width and 1080 high and I want to load them in a Image View with this code:

```
File imgFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/com.My.Package/files/Pictures/Sun.jpg");                
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                zoomImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

But on **Android 6.0** (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge) I'm getting this **error**, on **Android 5** (HTC One) it's **working pretty well**:

> W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3240x5760, max=4096x4096)

**So now to the Question:**
Is there a way to avoid this error and without a quality drop (I will need this quality, because you can zoom the Image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try loading it with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

The procedure is pretty straight forward and its fast and there won't be any OOM hopefully

Just compile this in your  `build.gradle`

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and then

```
Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(imgFile)
    .into(zoomImage);
```

and that's it, you will never face `OOM` again hopefully, I worked with images in my many apps and I have never faced `OOM` with it.

Hope it helps

Comment: does it chache the pictures?

Comment: by default it does but if you don't want to do that you can simply add `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` and it won't cache the image

Comment: It gives me this error if I try to load a image, stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide;

Comment: I think your using eclipse, right? you should try clean build, restart

Comment: No, Android Studio

Comment: Such issues can be simply resolved by cleaning the project and restarting the IDE

Answer (score 0):

As your error points out, your image is too large to load.

Basically right now you are loading the whole image into memory.

You have to get a smaller /scaled down version of the bitmap.

You can easily do this using BitmapFactory.Options,

Here is a link which goes into detail on the recommended technique to use for this: developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: But will I loose quality and why isn't it working on Android 6 but on Android 5?

Comment: Image quality is not necessarily focused on the Android version but can also vary from phone to phone. Your app cannot even handle the the current bitmap, so quality should be the least of your concerns. I would advise running some tests using a different sample size.

Comment: But without the "high" quality you won't see anything if you zoom in.

Comment: I see the size above is even 3240x5760, way to big.

Comment: I don't know the exact error px, but I saved the images as 1920/1080, so this can't be to big

Comment: Try this approach, when the image is zoomed out you load image with lower quality, because user wouldn't see difference, but when user zoom in you would load only part of high quality image which is visible for user.

Comment: @MyWay sounds ok, but it sounds, quite complicated, do you have some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check ["Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271020/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture)

and [Prevent bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633638/prevent-bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture-android)

It has the same error with your log